# JiBX (org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Unable to access binding information for class...)

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jar, jibx

has anyone used JiBX before? [JiBX website](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/index.html)

I keep getting this error when attempting to run as it attempts to bind:

org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Unable to access binding information for class ....

I am using Netbeans and it does not work but it works for my co-worker using Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the binding definition was compiled into your class files.

Have a look at the JiBX-[FAQs](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/faq.html#nobind) and the [JiBX binding compiler](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/bindcomp.html) ([Building with  other IDEs](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/bindcomp.html#ide-use)) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

in maven just need to configure plugin as below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jibx.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/java/com/lute/serviceAccessor/farelogix/domain</schemaBindingDirectory>
                    <includeSchemaBindings>
                        <includeSchemaBindings>*-Binding.xml</includeSchemaBindings>
                    </includeSchemaBindings>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bind</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

That will do !!